# Expected server HTML to contain a matching <tag> in <tag>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

We are using nextjs and getting this error at page refresh (or first load)

My error is:

```
react-dom.development.js:88 Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <tag> in <tag>.
```

The code of our functional component looks like this:

```
export default MyComponent () {

  if(! props.something){  // ← this is causing the problem.
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <>
     HTML here ...
    </>
  )
}
```

From my understanding, SSR is different from client side rendering and this is why react is complaining.

The app is working fine but this error is showing in the console and we don't want to have many errors being thrown there as this may prevent us from seeing the real errors when they happens.

---

#### Solution:

The solution is to use dynamic imports and and wrap the component call into:

```
const MyDynamicComponent = dynamic(() => import('./myComponent'), {ssr: false});

//use it:
<MyDynamicComponent />

//OR :

const MyDynamicComponent = dynamic(() => import('./myComponent'))

//use it:
{typeof window !== 'undefined' && (
  <MyDynamicComponent />
)}
```

Comment: Is that space after the exclamation mark a typo? Or is that in the code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

May be importing your component dynamically should solve this.
Below is the link you can refer;
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import

Comment: Please avoid posting [link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). This should either be a comment or you need to include the essential parts of those links in the question itself

Comment: Actually this was my first time answering the questions. Any ways I will remember this advice. Thanks.

Comment: @Zeeshan Thanks that was it... But not only, I had to wrap the component with `{typeof window !== 'undefined' && (`. I will accept your answer and update my question with the full solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for solution of a similar problem, but I was using react-window lib and the problem appeared to be in it. I passed different height to it, depends on whether it's loading on server or client, so it gave me back different elements.

My solution was to pass the same height at the beginning, but to change it to `window.innerHeight` on `useEffect` ( = on client load).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

When this happened to me on a Next project, I had not nested my html table elements properly. Specifically, didn't wrap my `<tr>` in a `<tbody>`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

the code is executed first on the server after in the browser in my case this is why i get this error and other error with style component like :
`Warning: Prop` className `did not match. Server: "CardUserInfo....`

so this link help :
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17443
[enter link description here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17443)
and the solution for me like montienned in this disscussion implement useState useEffect

> ```
> const [mount, setMount] = useState(false)
>    useEffect(() => {
>      setMount(true)
>       
>    }, [ ])
>   return mount&&(
>     <InfoUserCard/>)
> ```

Answer (score -1):

In my case the console error displaying `Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <sup> in <span>.` using Safari Web Browser in development ONLY, i.e. `localhost:3000` . Just get rid of this boring error by using Chrome Web Browser.

This boring error will not be exist in production with Safari Web Browser.